# Google auth modal getting closed in capacitor app ios

Tags: ios, google-signin, capacitor

I am working on an app that needs a Google login. I used react and capacitor(not ionic) with the help of the library

```js
@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth
```

It working fine with android, but in ios the intent for the login is opening for few seconds the got stucked. I have done all the nessary steps written by the repository maintainer. Any kind of help will be atime saver for me.